# Using Crypto.js in meteor

Tags: javascript, include, global-variables, meteor

I am trying to include some crypto.js libraries in a meteor js app (meteor version 0.6.4.1).

- http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js
- http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js

When I copy and paste the contents into the server/main.js file it works fine, but this makes it very un-readable.

When I put the libraries in separate files in the server directory (I also tried placing them in the lib directory) I get the error `ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined`.

gist of server/main.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
    encrypt:function(bundleID){
        return CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(string, 'something');
    }
});
```

I also tried changing the first line of the hmac-sha256.js file from

```
var CryptoJS=CryptoJS||function(h,s){...
```

to:

```
CryptoJS=CryptoJS||function(h,s){...
```

to make it global, but this also did not work.  How do I include this library properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your application dir create folder 'packages/cryptojs' and put there files:

- hmac-sha256.js
- enc-base64-min.js
- package.js

packages / cryptojs / **package.js**:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "CryptoJS"
});

Package.on_use(function (api, where) {
  api.add_files(['hmac-sha256.js'], ['client','server']);
  api.add_files(['enc-base64-min.js'], ['client','server']);
});
```

You need to modify **hmac-sha256.js** by changing beginning of line 7 from:

```
var CryptoJS=CryptoJS||function(h,s){
```

to:

```
CryptoJS=function(h,s){
```

After that, you can use it:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", "secret");
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);    
console.log(hashInBase64)
```

[Example source](http://jokecamp.wordpress.com/2012/10/21/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/)

Comment: So this did work locally, but when I finally pushed to heroku (using this build pack: https://github.com/v8squirrel/heroku-buildpack-meteor) the app crashes with this error: `ReferenceError: Package is not defined`.  It does run on heroku when I paste the contents of the crypto files to the bottom of my server.js file.

Answer (score 1):

I followed as parhelium's guide, but still not work, then I found new way to fix this issue: 
Just replace line 7 in hmac-sha512.js to this one to globalize CryptoJS object:

`this.CryptoJS=this.CryptoJS`

Fix the same for other cryptojs. To use with Base64, you must make sure the base64.js is loaded after other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is due to the variable scoping in meteor. Try putting the cryptojs library files in `/server/compatibility`. This way the cryptojs library can be accessed in other files.

You could also get it working without putting it in `/compatibility` by removing the `var` used in the cryptojs source files. The thing is if you do this its harder to keep the files up to date.

Comment: Placing them in `/server/compatibility` did not work.  The docs only mention `/client/compatibility` (tried there too, didn't work).  Maybe it doesn't work for both?

Comment: Try `/compatibility` to see if that works? What about removing the `var` from `var CryptoJS` in each of the JS files?